# How to refactor a class as a hook to manage a stack in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I need a stack to manage some labels' states. At first, I declare them as ref like this: `const stack = React.useRef([]), const index = React.useRef(0)`, and I visit the stack and maintain it manually.

After that, I try to abstract them as a independent class:

```js
import { Label } from '../interface/basic'
import { groupBy } from '../utils/categorys&colors'

export interface Can {
  redo: boolean
  undo: boolean
  reset: boolean
  save: boolean
}

export interface State extends Array<Label> {}

export class StateStack {
  private stateStack: State[] = []
  private index: number = 0
  can: Can

  constructor(initialState?: State) {
    if (initialState) {
      this.stateStack.push(initialState)
      this.index = 1
    }
    this.updateCan()
  }

  reset() {
    this.stateStack = []
    this.index = 0
    this.updateCan()
    return this
  }

  nowState() {
    this.updateCan()
    return this.stateStack[this.index - 1]
  }

  nextState() {
    this.index += this.can.redo ? 1 : 0
    return this.nowState()
  }

  prevState() {
    this.index -= this.can.undo ? 1 : 0
    return this.nowState()
  }

  resetState() {
    if (this.can.reset)
      this.index = this.index !== 1 ? 1 : this.stateStack.length
    return this.nowState()
  }

  pushState(newState: State) {
    this.stateStack = this.stateStack.slice(0, this.index)
    this.index = this.stateStack.push(newState)
    return this.nowState()
  }

  updateCan() {
    this.can = {
      redo: this.index < this.stateStack.length,
      undo: this.index > 1,
      reset: this.stateStack.length > 1,
      save: this.index > 1 || this.index < this.stateStack.length
    }
  }

  groupedState() {
    return this.nowState() ? groupBy(this.nowState(), 'categoryName') : {}
  }
}
```

then I declare a state in the top layer like this: `const stateStack = useState(new StateStack())`, For the most part, it works well but some little problems in re-rendering.

So I tried to refactor it as a hook but fail. Can someone help me reconstruct this class?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a class component into a React function component?

Comment: @DrewReese Actually it's not, this question is more like some example of which custom hook to handle login state or else, but I don't know which is the best practice, because I saw some examples only use Ref to declare the variable and use update hook in 'react-use' lib to trigger re-render and some use reducer. It really confuses me.

Comment: So you aren't trying to convert a class component into a function component? What are you trying to do then? React hooks can only be used in function components and other custom hooks. It seems you've an initial task then to convert this class component and logic into a function component so it ***can*** use React hooks.

Comment: @DrewReese Emmm, nope. I want to custom a hook that can store a stack and offer its handles. The answer below is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For React to redraw state changes you must use setState actions. You can obtain one from the second element of the return array of useState()

I recomend you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-state-handler

or build your own custom hook:

```
 function useStateHandler<H extends StateHandler<T>, T>( handlerClass : new ( s : React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>) => H, initial_value: T | (() => T)) : [T, H]  {
  const [st, setSt]                 = React.useState<T>( initial_value );  
  const [handler, setHandler ]      = React.useState<H>( () => new handlerClass( setSt ) );
  
  handler.state = st;

  return [ st, handler ];
}

abstract class StateHandler<T> {
  
  state?            : T;
  setState          : React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>; 

  constructor( sts : React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>> ) { this.setState = sts }

}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your patience.